# PHP getbyhostname domain code doesn't work on my webserver

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I found a php code online where you can type your domain in website and it says the status for it, if it's available or registered. And It worked on a company hosted webserver, but when I try to put It on my server it always says that the domain is available (getbyhostname doesnt work). Can someone help me figure this out?

The php code:

```
        <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        if(isset($_GET['domain'])){
            $domain = $_GET['domain'];
            if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
                echo 'Domain is registered';
            }
            else {
                echo 'This domain is available';

            }
        }

    ?>
```

My webserver php info: http://ver.lt/phpinfo.php

My webserver apache version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

The webserver php info that the code worked on: https://vairenis.serveriai.lt/PHP/

Comment: I've noticed there's also a [gethostbynamel()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php). Worth trying, but I think you might have a problem with the domain resolver. The first note there also has a tip: Add a dot after the domain.

Comment: Might want to try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php ; `checkdnsrr(idn_to_ascii($domain), 'A')` should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a particularly crude and unreliable bit of code. It is simply doing a DNS lookup on whatever you type - which is not the same thng as checking if a domain is registered. The most likely reason it is always failing is that your server is not configured to allow DNS lookups. This is a relatively cheap and simple security measure - we can't fix it. You need to speak to your hosting provider.

If you actually want to find out if a domain really is available you should be using whois ([rfc3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912)) and querying the Regional Internet Registries.